# Background Image on div element not scaling correctly on Dolphin browser

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, dolphin-browser

I'm trying to make a fully responsive website using HTML, CSS and minor Javascript.

I've managed to achieve this across Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE. However Dolphin browser causes a malformed layout.

I have a background image on my div element which is not fully scaled and is cut off about 30% or so down the divs height.

I'm done some research and came up with nothing specific about Dolphin to cause this behaviour.

```
.cover-image {
background-image: URL("Images/background.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
height:90%;
}
```

Comment: Background-attachment: fixed; is disabled in some browsers (Safari on iPhone) for example. This could be the case.

Comment: @Deka87 is correct about `background-attachment: fixed` on Dolphin - see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/backgrounds-borders/mobile.html. Fwiw, though it can be a fun challenge to make a site that's compatible with *every* browser, as of this writing most devs I know [yes, anecdotal] will only test Chrome, Safari, Firefox, mobile Safari, IE ≥ 9 (possibly ≥ 8, or possibly only ≥ 10, depending and the shop), and the latest Edge.

Comment: @henry & Deka87 Thanks for your comments guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the height of the body to **em units** rather than **vh units** (viewport height) and this seemed to solve my issue on Dolphin while maintaining the same appearance on other browsers.